# Replace NaN values in list of cols with mean of other list of cols

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe with NaNs:

```
  Col1 Col2  Col3  Col4
0    A    c   1.0   2.0
1    A    c   3.0   6.0
2    B    c   5.0   NaN
3    A    d   6.0   4.0
4    A    c   NaN   1.0
5    A    d   NaN   3.0
6    B    c   5.0   4.0
```

I want to replace the missing values present in columns with labels in the list `cols`

The value to be replaced is computed as the mean of the non-missing values of the corresponding group. Groups are formed based on the values in the columns with labels in the list `condition_cols`

For example:

```
condition_cols = ['Col1', 'Col2']

cols = ['Col3', 'Col4']
```

After replacing the NaNs the dataframe would look like this:

```
  Col1 Col2  Col3  Col4
0    A    c   1.0   2.0
1    A    c   3.0   6.0
2    B    c   5.0   4.0
3    A    d   6.0   4.0
4    A    c   2.0   1.0
5    A    d   6.0   3.0
6    B    c   5.0   4.0
```

I tried taking the mean of duplicates of `condition_cols` but the calculated mean is for every group not specific to any group.

Answer (score 6):

You can `groupby` the dataframe on `condition_cols` and `transform` using `mean`, finally use `fillna` to fill the missing values:

```
df = df.fillna(df.groupby(condition_cols).transform('mean'))
```

Result:

```
  Col1 Col2  Col3  Col4
0    A    c   1.0   2.0
1    A    c   3.0   6.0
2    B    c   5.0   4.0
3    A    d   6.0   4.0
4    A    c   2.0   1.0
5    A    d   6.0   3.0
6    B    c   5.0   4.0
```